# parsing xml file with qtxml c++

Tags: c++, xml, qt

i'm just trying to parse an xml file using QtXml lib , so i need some help b'cause i don't understand how it's work :$

so this is my xml file config.xml :

```
<configuration>
  <user>
    <foo>Something</foo>
    <bar>Something too</bar>
  </user>
  <dll_version>
    <v1>appv1</v1>
    <v2>appv2</v2>
    <v3>appv3</v3>
  </dll_version>
</configuration>
```

note : dll version it's a function that get version of an app from reg and compare it to value in xml file .

what i want to do :

- Create function like : GetConfValue(QString conftype, QString confname) 
  that return the Config Value example : GetConfValue("user", "foo") return "Something"

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once in past, I also needed similar functionality. I used code as below. This may not be best solution, but i worked for me.

```
QString GetConfValue(QString conftype, QString confname) {
  QString ret = "";
  QFile file("config.xml");
  if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
    QXmlStreamReader reader;
    reader.setDevice(&file); //(file);
    reader.readNext();
    while (!reader.atEnd()) {
      if (reader.name() == "configuration" && reader.isStartElement()) {
        reader.readNext();
        while (!reader.atEnd()) {
          if (reader.name() == conftype && reader.isStartElement()) {
            reader.readNext();
            while (!reader.atEnd()) {
              if (reader.name() == confname && reader.isStartElement())
                return reader.readElementText();

              reader.readNext();
            }
          }
          reader.readNext();
        }
      }
      reader.readNext();
    }
  } else
    qDebug() << qPrintable(file.errorString());
  return ret;
}
```